# Android Studio ActivityMain.kt not finding IDs of TextView, Buttons etc from activity-main.xml

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-activity, textview

I'm trying to learn programming. Using Android Studio I have created an
TextView and and Button in `activity_main.xml` and now I'm trining to use this two in `MainActivity.kt` but Android Studio cannot find the IDs of my Textview nor of my button. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

OS ManjaroLinux
Android Studio v. 4.1.1 installed by Flatpack
using Kotlin as programming language

Images of my problem

[Button declaration activity_main.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0RZE.png)

[TextView declaration activity_main.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCTwP.png)

[MainActivity.kt error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw7Zq.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer ids of components using R.id.*.
For example, if the id is defined by :

```
android:id="@+id/buttonTxt"
```

Then refer it by :

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonTxt)
```

The same applies for any resources like strings (R.string.*), colors, dimens etc.

Comment: Thank you, with your solution it is working, but I thought that by using Kotlin instead of Java it is not necessary anymore to use the findViewById. 
I'd read this one https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/ as I had to decide if learning java or Kotlin, and there it tolds me. 
Now I'm confused.

Comment: You can avoid usage of findViewById by using Kotlin extensions.
From what I understand, Kotlin extensions help to remove such simple function calls by handling these calls themselves. If you generate the Java code for such Kotlin extensions, you should find the findViewById in the generated java.